# Static on Wakeup - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, suspend, wakeup

I have a Sony Vaio VPCZ133GX with a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.

When I open the lid and wake it up it makes static noises that earned me some glares here in the library.

Here's a video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aq8nSpqqlNI

Here's a picture of my 
[AlsaMixer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C3A6.png).

Any ideas?